# Resize dev/sda2 Ubuntu VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, vmware-workstation

Using VMWare Workstation 15 Player (15.5.6) on Win10 host, Ubuntu 18.04 guest. I had originally 10GB disk attached to this VM. Started getting error `no space left on device`.

Deleted /tmp (`rm -rf /tmp/*`).  Increased the 10GB Disk size to 25GB, added another disk 20GB. But **the VM is not recognizing the new disk or the new increased size**. *(Yes I did restart work station and VM)*

```
:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /dev
tmpfs           422M  6.7M  415M   2% /run
/dev/sda2       9.8G  9.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/loop4       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/gedit/605
/dev/loop1       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9993
/dev/loop3      162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
```

You can see `/dev/sda2 shows 10GB` only and `0 aval`. So I think this is the problem.

Tried looking at `cfdisk` - (never used it before) - but somehow it also does not recognize beyond 10GB. Pretty much I can do anything on this VM - *barely can boot it* - how to solve this.

**Update 1**

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/fd0p1      2425393296 4850786591 2425393296  1.1T 90 unknown
/dev/fd0p2      2425393296 4850786591 2425393296  1.1T 90 unknown
/dev/fd0p3      2425393296 4850786591 2425393296  1.1T 90 unknown
/dev/fd0p4      2425393296 4850786591 2425393296  1.1T 90 unknown

Disk /dev/sdb: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

GPT PMBR size mismatch (20971519 != 52428799) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sda: 25 GiB, 26843545600 bytes, 52428800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A6944258-6EA8-4968-BA0A-E48315D8CEB6

Device     Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 20969471 20965376  10G Linux filesystem

~$ parted -l
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
Model: NECVMWar VMware SATA CD00 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 68.0MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr1 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr1
has been opened read-only.
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sr1: 889MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End    Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B  6143B  4096B                Apple
 2      663MB  666MB  2523kB               EFI

$ lsblk -o name,fstype,size,fssize,mountpoint,label,model,vendor
lsblk: unknown column: fssize,mountpoint,label,model,vendor

$ lsblk -o name,fstype,size
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE
fd0               1.4M
loop0  squashfs  96.6M
loop1  squashfs  62.1M
loop2  squashfs  97.1M
loop3  squashfs 161.4M
loop4  squashfs  17.9M
loop5  squashfs  55.3M
sda                25G
├─sda1              1M
└─sda2 ext4        10G
sdb                20G
sr0    iso9660   64.9M
sr1    iso9660    848M

~$ lsblk -o name,fstype,size,mountpoint,label,model,vendor
NAME   FSTYPE    SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL                           MODEL   VENDOR
fd0              1.4M
loop0  squashf  96.6M /snap/core
loop1  squashf  62.1M /snap/gtk-
loop2  squashf  97.1M /snap/core
loop3  squashf 161.4M /snap/gnom
loop4  squashf  17.9M /snap/gedi
loop5  squashf  55.3M /snap/core
sda               25G                                            VMware  VMware,
├─sda1             1M
└─sda2 ext4       10G /
sdb               20G                                            VMware  VMware,
sr0    iso9660  64.9M            CDROM                           VMware  NECVMWa
sr1    iso9660   848M            Ubuntu-Server 18.04.3 LTS amd64 VMware  NECVMWa
```

Comment: Start with `parted -l` or `fdisk -l`. Do they show you the increased disk (not fs) size on the first disk, and the second empty disk? This command will also help you: `lsblk -o name,fstype,size,fssize,mountpoint,label,model,vendor` Post the output of the commands and I'll add to the answer how you should proceed.

Comment: By adding another disk you've simply made a new device usable on the system, you haven't expanded your storage on the root drive (sdb is your 'new drive')Nor have you expanded the **partition** first so that it can use the excess space on the disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the increased size of `/dev/sda`: the guest OS can see the new size of the virtual disk, but you also need to resize the `sda2` partition and the file system it contains to be able to use the additional storage space.

One way to do that (alternatively, use the graphical tool [GParted](https://gparted.org/), which will take care of most of the following steps in a single operation):

0. Make sure you have a full backup of all the important data on the virtual machine. Possibly take a backup of the full VM image. Growing an on-line ext4 file system and the containing partition can be done on Linux, but you should never consider it a 100% safe operation.
1. Start `sudo parted /dev/sda`.
2. Print the partition table and take note of the `End` sector of the last line:

   ```
   unit s print free
   ```
3. Resize the `sda2` partition (it *should* be shown by `parted` as `2`):

   ```
   resizepart 2
   ```

   answering "yes" if `parted` warns you about the partition being in use and asks for confirmation; type in the number you obtained in step (2)—the last available sector on the device—appending the `s` (sectors) unit to it, when `parted` asks you for the end sector (you may then be asked to accept a slightly different final sector out of alignment reasons; that would be fine).
4. Print the partition table again (same as point (2)) to confirm that `sda2` has been resized.
5. Quit `parted`.
6. Use `lsblk /dev/sda` to make sure the kernel is aware of the resized partition. If its shown size is still `10G`, use `sudo partprobe -s` to refresh it and check it again.
7. Resize the file system:

   ```
   sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2
   ```

   You may be asked to run `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda2` before being able to resize the file system. Do it and then retry the `resize2fs` command.
   When given no size argument, `resize2fs` grows the file system to match the size of the containing partition.
8. Use `df -h /dev/sda2` to verify the new size.

About the newly added virtual disk, `/dev/sdb`: I'd suggest you not to use it and, if needed, grow `/dev/sda` further instead. You may want to remove the image that backs `sdb` on the host and add that storage space to `sda` before going through the above steps.

Comment: - Thanks. Went thru he steps - noted the end sector. It prompts with End?  20969472s?  But this is actually Start sector - the End sector is 52428766s.  **What do I do here** ?

Comment: Type in the End sector of the free space. This isn't dangerous, as long as you type a bigger number than the End sector of `sda2`.

Comment: Yes I did that - it worked shows 25G `lsblk /dev/sda
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  25G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   1M  0 part
└─sda2   8:2    0  25G  0 part /`

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0

this error is returned when you try parted .

disconnect any cd/dvd rom device in vmware and retry the same command [parted ].

Comment: I do not have any cd/dvd rom device attached to work station. But it does list the storage CD/DVD as SATA `.iso`