# In an Ubuntu VM in VMWare I increased the hard disk space, how do I add that to the file system?

Tags: filesystems, virtual-machine, resize2fs

I have an Ubuntu (v20.04) VM in VMWare. I increased (2x from 20G to 40G) the hard disk size. How do I add that space to the file system?

From `lsblk`, I have the following: `sda` is 40G type disk which is correct (2x previous)

```
NAME                          SIZE  TYPE
sda                           40G   disk
sda1                          1M    part
sda2                          1G    part  /boot
sda3                          19G   part
   |   
   L -ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    19G   lvm  /
```

Then I try to do `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3`
and I get

```
Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda3
Couldn't find filesystem superblock.
```

I was trying to follow some of the techniques in the question
[Resize dev/sda2 Ubuntu VMWare](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610129/resize-dev-sda2-ubuntu-vmware/610154#610154?newreg=03d800f9a0304618966a950a3f4ed98b)
But I get to step 7 and do the resize and get this error.

Is there a better way to go about this or is more simply is there a way to get the extra space into my filesystem.

(I would love to use `gparted` but I can't seem to make room for it to install - if I figure out a working way to add the extra space, that will be one of the first utilities I'll add!)

Answer (score 5):

You can't resize an `extN` filesystem on `/dev/sda3` because it's not a filesystem partition. If you look at the `lsblk` output it's marked as a partition containing an LV, which means it's a partition containing Logical Volumes. The LV is what you want to resize, but you first need to resize the partition.

**If any commands fail, or return unexpected output, STOP RIGHT THERE.**

Resize the partition:

```
parted /dev/sda print                # Check you have exactly three partitions
parted /dev/sda resizepart 3 100%    # Extend the third
parted /dev/sda print                # Confirm the new partition size
```

Resize the PV (Physical Volume) that contains the Volume Group ("ubuntu-vg") containing Logical Volumes:

```
pvresize /dev/sda3
  Physical volume "/dev/sda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
```

Now you can extend the LV ("ubuntu-lv"), adding 10GB to its size (for now):

```
lvextend --size +10g --resizefs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```